# Sci Fi book where humans go into the alien forest and come out with mutations

Tags: story-identification

This book has a woman with electronic wings on the cover. Alien life comes on a meteor and starts to flourish on earth. There are these little robots called LUVs that can attach symbiotically to humans. Humans also go into the alien forests and come out with mutations. Like electronic wings.

Comment: Electric wings doesn't sound like mutations, tbh.

Answer (score 2):

The book you are describing sounds like [Evolution's Shore](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1138391.Evolution_s_Shore) by Ian McDonald. (Also released in some countries as "Chaga"), the first book of his Chaga series. The cover of the Evolution's Shore version depicts a woman with butterfly wings which display images, as can be seen by following the link I just included.

From one of the user reviews at the link:

> a meteorite crashes in Africa, and starts growing. A zone of alien life starts spreading from the impact site, and changing the landscape. It's not dangerous, but the changed zone keeps spreading - and then people realise that animals, people and plants inside the zone are being altered into Something Else